# Forms change style of input "text" to alert user if they click on the box and leave it empty

Tags: javascript, css, html, forms, validation

For this form, stroke will be red to alert user **if they click on the box and leave it empty**.
**
I want to trigger this **without submitting the form**.
Can i do this with only HTML5 and CSS. How?
If i need JavaScript what is the code?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuYGA.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
 .invalid{
    background: Red;

    }
```

HTML:

```
  <input type="text" id="mytxt" />
```

Jquery:

```
$(function(){
   $('#mytxt').blur(function(){
       if($(this).val() == '')
           $(this).addClass('invalid');
       else
           $(this).removeClass('invalid');
   });
})
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/45ajS/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the loseFocus event of the textbox to check if it has content. If not, assign it a class in javascript like ".required" which will be styled in css to have a red border.

Here is some code in a fiddle that might help: http://jsfiddle.net/z2zwF/

Basically, it relies on this:

```
    if ($("#thisBox").text() == "")
    {
        $("#thisBox").addClass("required");
    }
```